# How can I create an OLAP data cube in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, olap-cube

I have a database in postgresql that I access using pgadmin4 or python(psycopg2). I read that postgresql allows OLAP cubes to be built on top of it, but can't find anything on HOW to create the cube. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Was not exactly sure what an *OLAP cubes* so I googled "Postgresql OLAP cube". Found Postgres documentation (back to version 8.3), a couple Postgres tutorials, how to create in Java and C#, several discussions/descriptions, and much more. Unless you have a very specific definition there is plenty of information. If you do have a very specific definition then you need to post it.